# UIView with glass effect

Tags: iphone, ios5, quartz-core

I want to create a view which should have a glass like effect. It should look shining as well. 
On that i want to add a UITextView which should appear transparent. I'm new to IPhone and not getting how to do this.
I don't want to add image. Wanna do programmatically. The view should look like as if it is a mobile screen.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "glass like effect" could you provide an image?

Comment: UIView should have a glass effect.We can achieve this by adding image but i want to do programmatically

Comment: you mean transparent view

Comment: check this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567022/glass-effects-uiview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do things if you don't want to use the image.

1. Add one `UIView` Use this code. And set gradient background color to it. Which will give you shiny glass like effect.

Here is the code:

```
.h file :

UIColor                                         *pinkDarkOp;
UIColor                                         *pinkLightOp;
CAGradientLayer                                 *gradient;

.m file :

img_TopBarView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,1024.0,50.0)];
img_TopBarView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
pinkDarkOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:15.0f/255.0 green:138.0f/255.0 blue:216.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0];
pinkLightOp = [UIColor colorWithRed:12.0f/255.0 green:91.0f/255.0 blue:183.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0];
gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = [[img_TopBarView layer] bounds];
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)pinkDarkOp.CGColor,(id)pinkLightOp.CGColor,nil];
gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7],nil];
[[img_TopBarView layer] insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:img_TopBarView];
[img_TopBarView release];
```

You have to take the values of pinkDarkOp and pinkLightOp as per your need. You can get this color code anywhere on google.

For eg : http://gradients.glrzad.com

1. For Creating the transparent `UITextView` you can use the alpha property of the `UITextView`.

I hope this helps.